# If $\|x\|\le\|y\|$, then prove that $\langle x,y\rangle \leq \langle y,y\rangle$.

Tags: normed-spaces

> If $\|x\|\le\|y\|$, then prove that $\langle x,y\rangle \leq \langle y,y\rangle$.

Comment: welcome to MSE, it is recommanded here to share us your own thoughts and what have you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality)

$$\phantom{asdsadsadas}$$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz!!!!Very simple..Got it Thanks....